# how to drag and drop a div on a website on the iPhone using jquery 

Tags: jquery, iphone, drag-and-drop

this is my code using jquery-ui , but it can't work on iphone :

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
                greedy: true,
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    //$(this).find('p').html('Dropped!');
                    $(this).append($(ui.helper).draggable("disable").addClass('end').find('p'))
                    $(ui.helper ).remove()
                }
            });
```

so what can i do ?

thanks

Comment: is drag and drop on a website on the iPhone feasible anyway? I mean, you normally use the "drag gesture" to scroll the page up or down. How do you want to solve this "gesture overloading"?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a read of this forum: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/drag-and-drop-on-the-iphone-ipod

The basic recommendation is to use jqTouch instead, although it's a bit of a bloated library. http://zeptojs.com/ may be better, although it doesn't specifically have a touch-hold-drag function.

http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html and http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 may be helpful too.

But really, draggable is not something touch devices are designed for, and your users may not understand what to do unless you explicitly tell them.